# What is the best database design for storing multiple subjects?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Recently I'm working on a project, in which I need save multiples subjects in my database, and numbers of subject will be change as per student's class. e.g: class "VII" has 6 subject (included 1 option subject), class "VIII" has 8 subjects (1 included option subject) and so on. Even the option subject can be different according to student's choice.

I'm using CheckedListBox control. Here is a screenshot.

[image]

I'm using MS Sql Server 2012. I'm facing difficulty to design database table. I can't understand should i create all the subject columns in my student table or ????(best way). Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a STUDENTS table, a SUBJECTS table, and a STUDENTSUBJECTS table linking them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are describing is something that is called a Many to Many relationship. Many Classes have Many students.

You will have a students table, a subjects table and then a table student_subject table which links both the primary keys of the students and subjects table.

[Reference: Many to Many](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php)

Answer (score 2):

If a `Student` can have multiple `Subjects`, *and* a `Subject` can have multiple `Students`, then that's a many-to-many relationship.  Which means there would need to be an intermediary table to link them.

Start with the tables for the objects themselves:

```
Student
----------
ID
Name
etc.
```

and

```
Subject
----------
ID
Name
etc.
```

Since these are independent aggregate root objects in the domain and neither one *owns* another one, their tables just contain information which describes that object.  A `Subject`, for example, could have a name and a description, maybe a list of pre-requisites, etc.

Then you create the relationship table between them.  A common practice is to just combine the names:

```
StudentSubject
----------
StudentID
SubjectID
```

If no two pairs of `Student` and `Subject` can be repeated, then the two foreign keys together can make the primary key.  If they *can* be repeated (if the same `Student` can have the same `Subject` more than once) then you'd probably want to add a separate primary key to the table.

At its simplest, all this table does is create the relationships between the records in the main tables.  However, this can potentially grow to be a domain entity in and of itself.  If there are any attributes which describe the relationship between a `Student` and a `Subject`, those would be added to this table.

Answer (score 2):

Your database schema should look something like this......

**Students**
 Student_ID (PK)
 
Student_Name 
etc .......

**Subject**
Subject_ID (PK)
 
Fee 
 
etc......

**Student_Subjects**
Student_ID FK Students(Student_ID) 
Subject_ID FK Subject(Subject_ID)
DateStarted 
etc.....